# Problem saving data and transfering to another activity (using FireBase)

Tags: java, android

I'm having problems while attempting to save data input (from the user) via two EditText and transferring it to another activity where it should be displayed as a ViewText.

Code from activity/data input

```
public class DatosBasicos extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText presion;
EditText ritmo;
Button atriaje;
String valorritmo;
String valorpresion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos_basicos);

    atriaje = (Button) findViewById(R.id.triaj);
    presion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.presion);
    ritmo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ritmo);
    atriaje.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            valorritmo = ritmo.getText().toString();
            valorpresion = presion.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(DatosBasicos.this, Triaje.class);
            i.putExtra("PRESION",valorpresion);
            i.putExtra("RITMO",valorritmo);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Code from activity/data output

```
public class Triaje extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView rit, pres;
String ritS, presS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_triaje);

    rit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ritmoval);
    pres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presionval);

    ritS = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PRESION");
    presS = getIntent().getExtras().getString("RITMO");

    rit.setText(ritS);
    pres.setText(presS);
}
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aplicaciontriaje, PID: 2569
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aplicaciontriaje/com.example.aplicaciontriaje.Triaje}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.aplicaciontriaje.Triaje.onCreate(Triaje.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8619', transport: 'socket'
```

WHAT SHOULD THE APP DO
I expect to get my data input into my Triaje activity and displayed in the two corresponding ViewText.
I get the following error: "App keeps stopping"

Comment: Is your second activity registered in the manifest?

Comment: It is:                                                                           <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aplicaciontriaje">
        <activity android:name=".Triaje" />

</manifest>

Comment: when the following error occurs "App keeps stopping", after app launching or clicking button in first activity?

Comment: Can you put the error trace of the logcat?

Comment: Ive identified the problem and is precisely in the "Triaje" activity. The app debug, launch, and executes with no problem. When i click the button that should take to to this activity with the data save from the user it gives me the error "App keeps stopping". If i delete the Triaje.java ive created to read the data it will work but obviously wont display data from previous activity. You can see the code from Triaje activity in the main post. I cant identify the problem.

Comment: I've added the log, i think. Please tell me if that is what you were refering to.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to debug the system ? Then you clearly understand exactly where the it gives you error! Then tell exactly in which line it gives error!

Comment: The app debugs works just fine. It will run, and execute perfectly just till the moment y click the buttom that should take from "DatosBasicos" activity to "Triaje" activity while saving data that the user gives as shown in the code.